# python3.5 PIL Image not displaying image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

The following code does not display the image `lists.jpg` (in current dir):
`print(dir(Image))` displays components; im.size, im.filename, im.format all return correct values.

What have I not done to display this jpg file?

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("lists.jpg")
im.show()  # did not work -  perhaps due to the environment Jupyter Notebooks
```

Solution: replaced module with another with immediate results.

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename='lists.jpg')
```

Comment: Why do you think it should be displayed? This code does nothing like that. The last line lists attributes of class `Image`.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is quite late to post but I will do it for new readers.

This problem arises in case of Jupyter Notebooks. Using show() does not display the image. So discard calling show() like in the code below. This will display the image in the output of the cell.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("lists.jpg")
im
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the image on screen:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("lists.jpg")
im.show()
```

See also http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/Image.html

Comment: Hugo,  I tired that and it did not work.  I am using Jupyter Notebooks as my environment could that be tyhe reason for the difficulty?

Comment: @AFBanks how did "it not work"? There are known problems if you're using Windows.